# Untar file in specific directory

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

I try to download a `tar.gz` file and uncompress it on `/tmp/apps`. 
However i don't want to uncompress it if the directory already exists.
If the file exists or even doesn't exist it is downloaded and uncompressed.
I cant find my code is missing a parameters on my `exec` block or if I made a mistake somewhere else.

I'm using Puppet 3.8.

[Gist file of my puppet](https://gist.github.com/zyriuse75/88653d03c17c5cc41dcaab96ddf21363)

Comment: We can advise you only about code you present in the question itself.  However, I suppose you're using an `exec` resource, so you should look into the `creates` parameter provided by that resource type, and maybe `onlyif` and `unless` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `puppet/archive` module, https://forge.puppet.com/puppet/archive. It will download the archive, check for existing files and even tidy up after itself.